# Difference between baseline and benchmark when performance testing REST endpoint?

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing

What is the Difference between baseline and benchmark when performance testing REST endpoint?
Let say I have SLA's given upfront and I am trying to test endpoints for what load that it can live with withing my SLA's.  What do I call those metrics?

Answer (score 0):

I would explain it as follows:

- `Baseline` - when you put your system under **anticipated** load to see whether your application is capable of handling the expected amount of users. The approach is better known as [Load Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_testing) so I think you can find a way more information on "load testing" rather than on "baseline testing"
- `Benchmark` - when you are trying to determine your application **boundaries**, i.e. determine how many users it theoretically can handle before it breaks or response time/throughput exceeds what is defined in the SLA (whatever comes the first). You can refer this as [Stress Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_testing) if you need more information.

See [Performance Testing vs. Load Testing vs. Stress Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/performance-testing-vs-load-testing-vs-stress-testing) article for more detailed explanation of the approaches